# web scraping using beautifulsoup: separating values

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I do web scraping using beautifulsoup. The web page has the following source:

```
<a href="/en/Members/">
                            Courtney, John  (Dem)                       </a>,
<a href="/en/Members/">
                            Clinton, Hilary  (Dem)                      </a>,
<a href="/en/Members/">
                            Lee, Kevin  (Rep)                       </a>,
```

The following codes work.

```
for item in soup.find_all("a"):
    print item
```

But, the codes return the following:

```
Courtney, John  (Dem)
Clinton, Hilary  (Dem)
Lee, Kevin  (Rep)
```

Can I just collect the names only? then the affiliation information separately? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '''
<a href="/en/Members/">Courtney, John  (Dem)</a>
<a href="/en/Members/">Clinton, Hilary  (Dem)</a>,
<a href="/en/Members/">Lee, Kevin  (Rep)</a>
'''

politicians = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for item in soup.find_all('a'):
    name, party = item.text.strip().rsplit('(')
    politicians.append((name.strip(), party.strip()[:-1]))
```

Because the names and the affiliation information both make up the text content of the `a` tags, you can't collect them separately. You have to collect them together as a string, then separate them. I have used the `strip()` function to remove unwanted whitespace, and the `rsplit('(')` function to split the text content on the occurrence of the left bracket.

**Output**

```
print(politicians)
[(u'Courtney, John', u'Dem)'),
 (u'Clinton, Hilary', u'Dem)'),
 (u'Lee, Kevin', u'Rep)')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) to split a string on multiple delimiters by crafting a regular expression pattern to split on.  Here I split on `(` and `)`

```
import re

for item in soup.find_all("a"):
    tokens = re.split('\(|\)', item)
    name = tokens[0].strip()
    affiliation = tokens[1].strip()
    print name
    print affiliation
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split

`re.split()` will return a list that looks like this:

```
>>> re.split('\(|\)', item)
['Courtney, John  ', 'Dem', '']
```

Grab entry `0` from the list for the name, stripping off white space from the ends.  Grab entry `1` for the affiliation, doing the same.

Comment: This works ... thanks ... I changed "item" to "item.text"